# Saving binary data to file row-by-row in python

Tags: python, loops, header, binary, save

I am trying to save data row-by-row in binary format (npy or npz, preferably).  Specifically, what I would like to do is:

1. Open/create a binary format file
2. Save header information to file (as a dictionary)
3. Generate a row of data
4. Save the row of data to file
5. Generate a new row of data
6. Save the row of data file
   ... repeat for all rows

My most recent attempt has been with savez.  When doing this I overwrite the previous row of data.  I want to *append* the data, however, not overwrite it.  The basic idea for the code is below:

```
    header = {'TIME': 20, 'POSITION': 30}
    testfile = open('test.npz', 'wb')
    np.savez(testfile, header)
    testfile.close()

    i = 0
    while i < 5:
         data = [i]*100 # generate row of data
         testfile = open('test.npz', 'wb')
         np.savez(testfile, data) #append data to current file
         testfile.close()
         i += 1
```

The datasets I am generating are very large, therefore I cannot store the entire set in memory and save at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open a file with the flag `'wb'` it means overwrite, binary.  You want to use the flags `'ab'` for append/binary.

Also, your open/close pattern is rather unnecessary.  You can just leave a file open, and flush your changes to disk from time to time to ensure partial progress are written.  I would wrap your entire code like so:

```
with open('test.npz', 'wb') as testfile:
    header = {'TIME': 20, 'POSITION': 30}
    np.save(testfile, header)
    i = 0
    while i < 5:
         data = [i]*100 # generate row of data
         np.save(testfile, data) #append data to current file
         i += 1
```

Naturally, change `'wb'` to `'ab'` if you have fresh data you want to append to the file, but you probably want to split out the writing of the header information with additional logic, perhaps split this up into two separate functions (i.e. `create_new` which creates the file and write the header, and `save_data` which opens the file in `'ab'` mode and appends data you want to save).

Comment: When I do as you suggested, I get an error when I try to open the data file.  Previously, using: `arrays = np.load('test.npz')`, `print arrays.files` would print the saved arrays.  Now I get the error: `zipfile.BadZipfile: Bad magic number for central directory`

Comment: However, it works using your method but using .npy format and np.save().  Initially, it looks seems that there is a single array saved (the header), but I can access all of the arrays using a loop. Example: `fp = open('test.npy', 'rb')`, `for i in range(5): print np.load(fp)`.

Comment: Just use `numpy.save` as it doesn't require dealing with the complexity of including compression.